# Should a MongoDB SubDocument that's never stored directly be a Document or a plain PHP class?

Tags: php, json, mongodb, symfony

I am creating a game where users can design their own levels (placing monsters, traps, quests etc.)  I'm using Symfony 2.3, and chose MongoDB because it's got Doctrine support.

When somebody edits a level and saves changes, the ZoneData JSON is submitted to the server.  The structure of this JSON is a handful of parameters (name, size, weather), and **hundreds** of ZoneObjects (which come in about 30 different types).  Each one of these ZoneObjects is an extension of a base class, for instance...

```
class ZoneObject extends Document {
    protected $xPos;
    protected $yPos;
}

class MonsterObject extends ZoneObject {
    protected $name;
    protected $challengeRating;
}
```

These ZoneObjects are only Documents right now simply because I know they're not Entities.  I'm not sure whether they should be Documents or simply plain classes.  They never need to be saved on their own, they're always part of ZoneData.  They do need to be validated however, and edited via forms.

So my question is - in a set up like this, would you make these Documents, or stick with Plain Old PHP Objects instead?  I'm concerned about how a MongoDB document with 500 embedded Sub-Documents is going to scale.

Apologies if I'm missing something simple here.

Thanks in advance,
James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB is very fast on inserts, and its NoSQL nature means that you'll be able to extend your documents with as much information as you need to store. The technology stack ensures that you can write very fast, but it may be harder to reference information, which I think is much more important for when the *game* runs. If I were designing a level, I would expect the initial setup to be a bit more processing intensive, but to have the level itself render very fast.

I would set up your *Objects as entities, and store them in different collections, based on their type. Monsters would go into the "monsters" collection, "Weather" into its own, etc. The reasoning behind this is that collection store documents with similar scope (which is absolutely true in the design you've presented, albeit with a bit less control, read below).

I would then have a "Zone" Entity, which has properties for *weather, monsters, environment, etc.*, and that links to the entries in each specific collection. The advantage here is that it is more distributed, and you have more control on the scope of your components.

Finally, I would feature a Level entity, which references the Zone entities which are associated to it.

The setup above allows you to easily reference information as you need it, and can generate reports, etc. on a particular zone. It also has the advantage that everything is much easier to test, and you can poll for information as you need it. Say you have a *map* which you display when a *player* enters a level. You may want to display weather or environment information, but you're not tied to retrieving all of the other information for that segment. When an action occurs in a zone, you would then display the appropriate information for that area, but given your better scope, you still have a lot of control over each element that you expect (i.e. You know you will have only one document for weather, but one or more for Monster).

By structuring things into entities, you also have access to Symfony's fantastic validation service, which really takes out a lot of the issues that you generally face when building forms and enforcing constraints.

Finally, it's always fair to remember that premature optimisation is the devil. There are many ways to increase access speed without restructuring your application (caching, Gearman, etc.) and you should think about what the most important thing is - getting something built and running for an alpha release, or providing a paid service that should be flawless.

I hope I've covered most of your concerns, but make sure to comment if not, and I'll update my answer!

Comment: Ok awesome.  Just to clarify (I'm fairly new to this), is your suggestion that I have separate Documents for each element (weather, NPC, monster, trap) in the Zone and relate them using MongoDB relations.  So, instead of having a 300K document that represents the whole Zone, a Zone would have a collection of Monster documents (for example), and therefore I'd be able to look up and edit a single monster directly?  I hadn't thought about doing it that way because of the amount of lookups (but yes, caching would be a must).

Comment: @james853 Hey man, that's exactly right. The huge advantage in this design is that your validation actually goes through entities, and the Validation service in Symfony helps out a lot with that, and with keeping things clean. As for amount of lookups, I think you're over-estimating. Even if a Zone has 100 elements added to it and you need to display **all of them** to the user, that's only 100 queries which you can cache, and that's the worst case scenario.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, in terms of performance, I can tell you that for a huge eCommerce platform, we had logging with MongoDB and we would store 100K entries/second using just three DB servers and a load balancer. The setup was fairly similar, and performance was really good when displaying data.

Comment: Ok fantastic.  Yeah, I think this is a much better way of doing it.